# Boolean fields not saving in a model form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form class that looks like this:

```
class ApplicationDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    worked_in_industry = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, 
                         choices=((1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No')), 
                         widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicantDetails
        fields = ('work_experience', 'license_level', 'license_duration',      
                  'expected_salary')
```

The field `worked_in_industry` is a `BooleanField` that I've modified to be rendered as Yes/No radio buttons.  My problem is that the field isn't saved when my form is processed...all the other fields are saved correctly except the radio button fields.  What's my problem?

In the processing view, I've also added:

```
if job.is_valid():
    application = job.save(commit=False)
    worked_in_industry = job.cleaned_data['worked_in_industry']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should include `"worked_in_industry"` in the `fields` Meta variable.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple...I'm almost beating myself up!! Thanks KillianDS